# Euler-Mascheroni (series&sequences)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

1) Explain why $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq \ln \frac{n+1}{n}$.

2) If $(t_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence given by $t_n= \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r}-\ln n$, prove that $t_n$ is decreasing and $0<t_n<1$.

3) Explain why $\lim_{n\to\infty} t_n$ exists.

For 1) I don't understand how one can explain it.

For 2) I used the formula $t_{n+1}-t_n$ and by using the the 1st part you get that it is decreasing but for the second one $t_{n+1}-0$ and $t_{n+1}-1$ don't seem to lead to any results.

For 3) part no clue.

Any opinions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for part 1: use the formula
$$ \int_n^{n+1} \frac{dx}{x} = \ln (n+1) - \ln n. $$

Hint for part 2: use the formula
$$ \int_1^n \frac{dx}{x} = \ln n - \ln 1. $$

Hint for part 3: any decreasing sequence which is bounded from below approaches a limit.

Comment: for part 1) it was given as you put it. But how does this actually correlate with the 1/(n+1)?

Comment: @curious_math Try using the fact that $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{x} \leq \frac{1}{n}$ for $x \in [n,n+1]$.

Comment: and for part 2, you don't use t(n+1)-0 and t(n+1)-1? how do you deal with the series? I end up with 1/(n+1)+sum(1/r)-ln(n+1) using the above (t(n+1)-0) but still stuck. I am sorry for bothering you, but I have never seen in uni class anything like this.

Comment: @curious_math Try to use the estimates $\sum_{k=2}^n \frac{1}{k} \leq \int_1^n \frac{dx}{x} \leq \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{k}$.

Comment: awesome! I used the estimate and found that 0<tn<1 as was asked. Does this estimate occur by repeatedly applying the same principle as in part 1?

Comment: That's right. It's a standard technique to estimate series with integrals or vice versa.